# How to make open graph token expiry readable in PHP - Making sense of facebook's string output

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, datetime, oauth, facebook-opengraph

When extending an oAuth token I want to get a readable date/time of Facebook's response for debugging purposes. I'm planning on doing this in PHP using `parse_str($fbstring) and date('D d M', $expires)`.

The raw string I get from FB looks like...

`string(224) "access_token=CAAFiJHGytDRTOhJyfyfYTUTYRYETedytB3V5QpRrfmbSDIzbwccz5XlEJIOY0pYvI7wKjPd9XrDvp3WoD3yhUrGUkkbTKwkzDx6xKOJgZD&expires=5178715"`

But the expiry, `5178715` seems too short to me. If I debug the actual token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) the expiry is much longer and different i.e `1418256000` (I have altered the example above so it won't work).

What is this short expiry facebook is giving me... and how can I display a readable date in PHP that represents what the token debugger gives me?

Note: I'm using the following CURL request URL in PHP to retrieve the string for the above output `"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=" . $serv["app_id"] . "&client_secret=" . $serv["app_secret"]."&fb_exchange_token=".$serv["access_token"]`

Comment: `expires=5178715` --- how many seconds left to expiration time.

Comment: Thanks! So why use seconds here, and a datetime in thier debugger. And how do I convert this to a readable datetime?

Comment: I have no idea why they do it, but there is no reliable way to convert it in point in time. `time() + 5178715` would give you an approximation. You could just ask FB API about the token expiration time using `/debug_token`

Comment: Is that to do with timezones? Will `time()` produce my client time or the PHP server time?

Comment: Feel free to submit this answer. It's matching up now with what the FB debugger says:)

Comment: Just drop it if you wish, it doesn't worth it :-)